# Functions and continuity

Tags: continuity, differential

Consider the function
$$f(x) = \frac{e^{-|x|}}{\max\{e^x , e^{-x}\}}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Then

a) $f$ is not continuous at some points
b) $f$ is continuous everywhere, but not differentiable anywhere
c) $f$ is continuous everywhere, but not differentiable at exactly one point
d) $f$ is differentiable everywhere

How to arrive at conclusion?

Comment: Have you tried graphing the function, via say a graphing calculator?

Comment: For any specific value of $x$, the denominator is either $e^x$ or $e^{-x}$.  Start by working out when it is one and when it is the other.

Comment: From graph, it is continuous for max{e^x, e^-x}. But determining differentiability?

Answer (score 1):

$\max\{e^{x},e^{-x}\}=e^{|x|}$. Then, $f$ is continuous because is composition of continous functions, etc

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

For $x\ge0$, $e^{-|x|}=e^{-x}$, $\max(e^x,e^{-x})=e^x$ and thus $\frac{e^{-|x|}}{\max(e^x,e^{-x})}=e^{-2x}$.

For $x\le0$, $e^{-|x|}=e^{x}$, $\max(e^x,e^{-x})=e^{-x}$ and thus $\frac{e^{-|x|}}{\max(e^x,e^{-x})}=e^{2x}$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark